# Reproducción exoplayer con HLS solo funciona con mi red wifi, cuando intento con la red móvil me da error 403

Tags: android, hls

Estoy implementando exoplayer 2.14.0 en una aplicación de android para reproducir videos en formato hls m3u8, pero solo funciona cuando estoy conectado a la red de mi casa: si activo los datos móviles o intento con otra red wifi me da el error:

> ```
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:580)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:383)
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:201)
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101)
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:64)
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:177)
>        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:417)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
> ```

Dejo código:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    public static String uriVideo = "https://yctr2qqvyayk0t4p.ezcdn654.net:8443/hls/wcnkeoiaz3tde.m3u8?s=mMWEkohXM_8Qs_6gUURc2w&e=1620905637";
    public static String uriVideo2 = "https://gofile.io/d/WaP8EI";
    int currentWindow = 0;
    long playBackPosition = 1;
    boolean playWhenReady = true;

    //Minimum Video you want to buffer while Playing
    public static final int MIN_BUFFER_DURATION = 40000;
    //Max Video you want to buffer during PlayBack
    public static final int MAX_BUFFER_DURATION = 50000;
    //Min Video you want to buffer before start Playing it
    public static final int MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER = 3500;
    //Min video You want to buffer when user resumes video
    public static final int MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER = 10000;

    HttpDataSource.Factory factory;


    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
    LoadControl loadControl;
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory;
    String userAgent;

    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory;


    private static final String USER_AGENT =
            "stagefright/1.2"

                    + " (Linux; Android "
                    + Build.VERSION.RELEASE
                    + ") "
                    ;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    private static final String DRM_SCHEME_EXTRA = "drm_scheme";
    private static final String DRM_LICENSE_URL_EXTRA = "drm_license_url";

    private static final String TAG = "";
    public static final ExoMediaDrm.Provider DEFAULT_PROVIDER =
            uuid -> {
                try {
                    return newInstance(uuid);
                } catch (UnsupportedDrmException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to instantiate a FrameworkMediaDrm for uuid: " + uuid + ".");
                    return new DummyExoMediaDrm();
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest1, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                // an ad is loaded.
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                //Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                // Handle the error
                //Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                mInterstitialAd = null;
            }
        });

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
        } else {
            //Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
        }

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        uriVideo = getIntent().getStringExtra("Url");

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        
        loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                .setAllocator(new DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
                .setBufferDurationsMs(MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
                        MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
                        MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
                        MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER)
                .setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
                .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true).createDefaultLoadControl();
        
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "Futbolplay");



        HlsPlaylistParser hlsPlaylistParser = new HlsPlaylistParser();
        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent, new DefaultBandwidthMeter());
        factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, 10000, 10000, true);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            //Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24){
            initPlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (Util.SDK_INT>=24){
            releasePlayer();
        }
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Util.SDK_INT < 24 || exoPlayer == null){
            initPlayer();
            hideSystemUi();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (Util.SDK_INT < 24){
            releasePlayer();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void hideSystemUi() {
        playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        );
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (exoPlayer != null){
            playWhenReady = exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
            playBackPosition = exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            currentWindow = exoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            exoPlayer.release();
            exoPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void initPlayer() {
        exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

        
        MediaSource Video = null;

        if (!uriVideo.equals(null)){
            Video = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(
                    dataSourceFactory
            ).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uriVideo.replace(" ", "%20")));
        }


        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        //exoPlayer.setMediaSource(Video);
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(Video);
        exoPlayer.prepare();
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        exoPlayer.seekTo(currentWindow, playBackPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


    }


}
```

Comment: De verdad no comprendo solo reproduce los videos hls con la red fija de mi casa en dispositivos fisicos y emulador... he probado con red movil, otro tipo de red fija, otros operadores de red movil y nada solo funciona con la red de mi casa

Comment: Siempre me marca Defaulthttpdatasouce error 403 pero solo reproduce con la red de mi casa con el resto me marca este error